# Playstation payment problem

Tags: ps4, psn

I am new here. I am really happy to see so many game enthusiasts here.

I have created new PlayStation Account. I have bought one game successfully with my credit card. The problem is, when I buy another game, I get the following error:

[image: a screenshot of the error message]

The error message is from the German store and roughly translates to:

> This transaction can not be processed at the moment. Please try again later, or try to place your order on the PlayStation®Store on your PlayStation® console.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Could you please translate the error message to English? It would make it easier for non German speakers like myself to help you.

Comment: It means: 
There has been an error, and we could not see the cart. If the problem continues shall stand, please consult the customer support

Comment: I have added a rough translation to the question body. I believe it is accurate enough.

Comment: I tried from the console, but the same error message.

Comment: I usually see this message when I try to log in using my phone (in mobile view). It doesn't appear very often on my PC or PS4, however. I believe it may be a temporary thing. That message *did* appear quite often when I tried to purchase something while on a very bad internet connection, though I'm not sure if it's coincidence or not.

Comment: No problem with internet, it is been 4 days getting this error message continously.

Comment: This sounds like a technical support question for Sony. Have you tried contacting them about it?

Answer (score 1):

It's been my experience that transactions that fail on the PSN website often work when being placed through the console itself. However since you said it fails with the same error on your console, the next step would be to contact the customer service department of your credit card issuer.

Sony uses some fairly strict payment method authentication because they instantly deliver non-tangible products that aren't expensive enough to warrant serious legal pursuit of someone in the case of fraud. As a result, if the address and name info they have for you isn't 100% identical to what your card issuer has, it won't go through. Unfortunately they give the same vague error message when a transaction fails no matter the reason; even if the transaction is explicitly being declined because of an info mismatch the message will still make it sound like a temporary problem and tell you to just try again later.

Your card issuer can quickly look up your transaction history and tell you whether or not the actual purchase was ever submitted by Sony, and if it has, they can tell you exactly what Sony said your info should be. When I was experiencing the same issue recently it turned out that the mistake was actually on the part of my card issuer; they had "Apt #xxx" for my apartment number in my street address while Sony only had "Apt xxx". That one-character mismatch was enough for the transaction to fail. My card issuer removed the '#' from my profile with them and the problem was instantly corrected.

Now if it turns out that your card issuer has no record of the transaction even being submitted it indicates the error is internal to Sony's store and you should contact PSN customer service. However since the first thing they'll likely suggest is to call your credit card company and do what I detailed above, at least you'll be able to tell them you already have and they had no record of the transaction.

Comment: Thank you, i have buy a game with same card settings and after 10 minute i can not!! I do not think this is a problem of credit card.

Comment: If your card worked at first that would indicate your issuer is bouncing back the attempted transaction. Since it is a new PSN account and the purchase that worked was your first one, there's a distinct possibility your card company automatically flagged it as suspicious activity and will decline further PSN purchases until you talk to them and verify it is indeed you making them. The first logical step is still to call your card company and ask if there's been any attempted authorizations from Sony, and if so, why they're being rejected.

Answer (score 0):

I agree in every point of @Barkode's answer, and comments.

In addition, you could try (in the meantime or for definitive) buying the digital version of the game through the Amazon online store; since Amazon credit policy isn't that strict.

Or the preferred method for me: buy the PS card (careful not the PlayStation Plus Subscription) from Amazon too (they send you a code almost instantly), and use the funds to buy what you like.